# Implementation of Policy Gradient Reward Design paper

Tags: python, machine-learning, multiprocessing

I've implemented the first experiment from the [Reward Design via Online Gradient Ascent paper](https://paperswithcode.com/paper/reward-design-via-online-gradient-ascent). I don't have any specific concerns, but it's my first time using multiprocessing or doing reinforcement learning, and I want to add this work to my portfolio. So I want to know if there is anything wrong with this code or if it can be improved in any way. The number of trials is 13 instead of 130 like in the paper because I don't have that much compute.

Main file:

```
import numpy as np
from agent import Agent
from environment import BirdEnv
from pgrd import PGRD
from gym.utils.seeding import np_random
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os
    

# 5 actions: move right, left, down, up, eat the worm
NUM_ACTIONS = 5 
#the agent observes the full state given by 9*agent_location + worm_location
NUM_STATES = 81
TAU = 100
GAMMA = 0.95
NUM_TRIALS = 13
TOTAL_TIMESTEPS = 5000


if __name__ == "__main__":
    rng_env, _ = np_random()
    env = BirdEnv(rng_env)
        
    for depth in range(7):
        print(depth)
        for alpha in [0, 2e-6, 5e-6, 2e-5, 5e-5, 2e-4, 5e-4, 2e-3, 5e-3, 1e-2]:
            print(alpha)
            for beta in [0, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9, 0.95, 0.99]:
                def run_trial(num_trial):
                    env.reset()
                    rng_agent, _ = np_random()
                    agent = Agent(depth, TAU, GAMMA, rng_agent, NUM_ACTIONS, NUM_STATES)
                    model = PGRD(agent, env, alpha, beta)
                    return model.learn(total_timesteps=TOTAL_TIMESTEPS, visualize=False)
                
                pool = Pool(os.cpu_count())
                try:
                    returns = pool.map(run_trial, np.arange(num_trials))
                    returns = np.sum(np.array(returns), axis=0) / num_trials
                finally:
                    pool.close()
                    pool.join()
                np.save("results/Result_depth_{}_alpha_{}_beta_{}.npy".format(depth, alpha, beta), returns)
```

agent.py:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import lru_cache

def softmax(action_values, tau):
    """
    Arguments: action_values - 1-dimensional array
    tau - temperature
    """
    preferences = action_values * tau
    max_preference = np.max(preferences)
    exp_prefs = np.exp(preferences - max_preference)
    return exp_prefs / np.sum(exp_prefs)

class Agent:
    def __init__(self, depth, tau, gamma, rng, nA, nS):
        self.nA = nA
        self.nS = nS
        self.depth = depth #depth of planning
        self.tau = tau #policy temperature
        self.gamma = gamma #discount rate
        #agent's model of the environment
        #N[s][a] =  {total: total_visits, 'counts': {s': x, ...}}
        #N[s][a][s'] - number of visits to s' after taking action s in state a
        #N[s][a][s`] / N[s][a][total] = Pr(s`|s, a)
        self.N = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: {'total':0, 'counts': defaultdict(lambda:0)}))
        self.rand_generator = rng
        
    def update(self, state, action, newstate):
        self.N[state][action]['total'] += 1
        self.N[state][action]['counts'][newstate] += 1

    def plan(self, state, theta):
        """ Compute d-step Q-value function and its theta-gradient at state""" 
        @lru_cache(maxsize=None)
        def _plan(self, state, d):
            """ Recursive memoized function"""
            reward_grad = np.zeros((self.nA, self.nS, self.nA))
            for a in range(self.nA):
                reward_grad[a,state,a] = 1
            if d == 0:
                action_values = theta[state]
                value_grad = reward_grad
            else:
                inc = np.zeros(self.nA)
                grad_inc = np.zeros((self.nA, self.nS, self.nA))
                for action in self.N[state].keys():
                    for state_next, count in self.N[state][action]['counts'].items():
                        values_next, grad_next = _plan(self, state_next, d-1)
                        action_next = np.argmax(values_next)
                        p = count / self.N[state][action]['total']
                        inc[action] += values_next[action_next] * p
                        grad_inc[action, state_next, action_next] += np.argmax(values_next) * p

                action_values = theta[state] + self.gamma * inc
                value_grad = reward_grad + self.gamma * grad_inc
            return action_values, value_grad
        return _plan(self, state, self.depth)
    
    def logpolicy_grad(self, value_grad, probas, action):
        """
        Arguments: 
        value_grad: nA x nS x nA
        probas: nA
        action: int
        Returns:
        grad: nS x nA
        """
        grad = self.tau * (value_grad[action] - np.tensordot(probas, value_grad, axes=1))
        return grad
    
    def policy(self, action_values):
        probas = softmax(action_values, self.tau)
        return probas

    def step(self, state, theta):
        action_values, value_grad = self.plan(state, theta)
        # compute the Boltzman stochastic policy parametrized by action_values
        probas = self.policy(action_values) #shape: nA
        # select action according to policy
        action = self.rand_generator.choice(np.arange(self.nA), p=probas)
        grad = self.logpolicy_grad(value_grad, probas, action)
        return action, grad
```

environment.py

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

MAP = ["CCC",
       " ==",
       "CCC",
       " ==",
       "CCC"]

class BirdEnv:
    """Bird looks for a worm"""
    metadata = {'render.modes': ['human']}

    def __init__(self, rng):
        self.nA = 5 #number of actions: right, left, down, up, eat the worm
        self.nC = 9 #number of cells in 3x3 grid
        self.nS = self.nC**2 # state = (position of bird, position of worm)
        self.ncol = 3 #number of columns in 3x3 grid
        self.rand_generator = rng
        #transitions[c][a] == [(probability, nextcell),..]
        self.transitions = {c : {} for c in range(self.nC)}
        def move(i, j, inc):
            cell_i = max(min(i + inc[0], 4), 0)
            cell_j = max(min(j + inc[1], 2), 0)
            #move according to action, if you can
            if MAP[cell_i][cell_j] == "=":
                cell_i = i
            elif MAP[cell_i][cell_j] == " ":
                cell_i += inc[0]
            cell = 3 * (cell_i // 2) + cell_j
            return cell
        for i, row in enumerate(MAP):
            for j, char in enumerate(row):
                if char == "C":
                    d = defaultdict(lambda:0)
                    for inc in [(0,1), (0, -1), (1, 0), (-1,0)]:
                        cell = move(i,j,inc)
                        d[cell] += 0.025
                    for action, inc in enumerate([(0,1), (0, -1), (1, 0), (-1,0)]):
                        cell = move(i,j,inc)
                        trans = d.copy()
                        trans[cell] += 0.9                     
                        self.transitions[3*(i//2)+j][action] = [(prob, nextcell) for nextcell, prob in trans.items()]
        #initial cell distribution (always start in the upper left corner)
        self.icd = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        self.cell = self.rand_generator.choice(np.arange(self.nC), p=self.icd)
        #initial worm distribution: in one of the three right-most locations at the end of each corridor
        self.iwd = [0, 0, 1./3, 0, 0, 1./3, 0, 0, 1./3]
        self.worm = self.rand_generator.choice(np.arange(self.nC), p=self.iwd)
        self.lastaction = 4
    
    def state(self):
        return self.nC * self.cell + self.worm
    
    def step(self, action):
        """Execute one time step within the environment"""
        reward = 0
        if action == 4:
            #try eating the worm
            if self.cell == self.worm:
                #move worm into one of the empty cells on the right
                self.worm = self.rand_generator.choice([(self.worm + 3) % self.nC, (self.worm + 6) % self.nC])
                reward = 1
        else:
            transitions = self.transitions[self.cell][action]
            i = self.rand_generator.choice(np.arange(len(transitions)), p=[t[0] for t in transitions])
            _, cell = transitions[i]
            self.cell = cell
        self.lastaction = action
        state = self.state()
        return state, reward

    def reset(self):
    # Reset the state of the environment to an initial state
        self.cell = self.rand_generator.choice(np.arange(self.nC), p=self.icd)
        self.worm = self.rand_generator.choice(np.arange(self.nC), p=self.iwd)
        
    def render(self, mode='human', close=False):
    # Render the environment to the screen
        outfile = sys.stdout
        desc = [["C", "C", "C"], ["C", "C", "C"], ["C", "C", "C"]]
        row, col = self.cell // self.ncol, self.cell % self.ncol
        desc[row][col] = "B"
        row, col = self.worm // self.ncol, self.worm % self.ncol
        desc[row][col] = "W"
        
        if self.lastaction is not None:
            outfile.write("  ({})\n".format(
                ["Right", "Left", "Down", "Up", "Eat"][self.lastaction]))
        else:
            outfile.write("\n")
        outfile.write("\n".join(''.join(line) for line in desc)+"\n")
```

pgrd.py

```
import numpy as np
class PGRD:
    def __init__(self, agent, env, alpha, beta):
        self.agent = agent
        self.env = env
        self.alpha = alpha #step size
        self.beta = beta 
        #theta is initialized so that the initial reward function = objective reward function
        self.theta = np.zeros((env.nS, env.nA))
        for cell in [2,5,8]:
            self.theta[10*cell, 4] = 1
        #variable to store theta gradient
        self.z = np.zeros((env.nS, env.nA))

    def learn(self, total_timesteps, visualize=False):
        state = self.env.state()
        total_reward = 0
        returns = []
        for i in range(total_timesteps):
            if visualize:
                print(i)
                self.env.render()
            action, grad = self.agent.step(state, self.theta)
            newstate, reward = self.env.step(action)
            total_reward += reward
            #update agent's model of the environment:
            self.agent.update(state, action, newstate)
            state = newstate
            #update theta
            self.z = self.beta * self.z + grad
            self.theta += self.alpha * reward * self.z
            #cap parameters at +-1:
            self.theta = np.maximum(self.theta, -1)
            self.theta = np.minimum(self.theta, 1)
            returns.append(total_reward / (i+1))
        return np.array(returns)
```

tests.py

```
import numpy as np
#print environment transitions:
def print_env(env):
    def pretty(d, indent=0):
        for key, value in d.items():
            print('\t' * indent + str(key))
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                pretty(value, indent+1)
            else:
                print('\t' * (indent+1) + str(value))
    pretty(env.transitions, indent=1)

def test_value_grad(agent):
    theta = np.random.rand(agent.nS, agent.nA)
    
    delta_theta = 1e-2 * np.random.rand(agent.nS, agent.nA)
    state = 0
    values1, grad1 = agent.plan(state, theta)
    
    values2, grad2 = agent.plan(state, theta + delta_theta)
    
    assert np.allclose(values2 - values1, np.tensordot(grad1, delta_theta, axes=2))
    
def test_policy_grad(agent):
    theta = np.random.rand(agent.nS, agent.nA)
    delta_theta = 1e-3 * np.random.rand(agent.nS, agent.nA)
    state = 0
    
    for action in range(5):
        values1, value_grad1 = agent.plan(state, theta)
        logprobas1 = np.log(agent.policy(values1))
        values2, value_grad2 = agent.plan(state, theta + delta_theta)
        logprobas2 = np.log(agent.policy(values2))
        grad = agent.logpolicy_grad(value_grad1, agent.policy(values1), action)

        assert np.allclose(logprobas2[action] - logprobas1[action], (grad * delta_theta).sum())
```